# CSS: Images are overlap (height) on laptop (1366x768) but don't when I shrink browser window (width)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, portfolio

I can't figure out what the hell I'm doing wrong. I've tried using ChatGPT to tackle this, but I can't get the images to responsively size appropriate where when I'm viewing on my laptop `(1366x768)` there is (1) no vertical scrolling and (2) the height of the images doesn't overlap. Keep in mind the width doesn't overlap already and the site already resizes to 3 rows of 2 columns when the window gets small enough (for smart phones). I haven't set a responsive height for the  element yet because every time I mess with it I seem to make the issue worse. I'm really new to using calc() so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here's the Code:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body,
div,
img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}


/* fill in color: with desired color based on chosen design */

nav ul li a:hover {
  color: green;
}


/* set max-height of image containers to 50% of viewport height minus nav bar height */

.nav-img {
  max-height: calc(50vh - 50px);
}

.container ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding-left: 0;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container ul li {
  list-style: none;
  flex: 0 0 calc(33.333333% - 20px);
  height: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container ul li img {
  height: auto;
  /* changed from 100% to auto */
  width: auto;
  /* changed from 100% to auto */
  max-height: 100%;
  /* remove if height: 100%;?? */
  max-width: 100%;
  /* remove if width: 100%;?? */
  display: block;
  /* object-fit: cover; */
  object-fit: contain;
  border-radius: 5px;
}


/* Media Query for smaller screens */

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .container ul li {
    flex: 1 0 calc(50% - 20px);
    height: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Portfolio 2 Totally Fake Tiny Home Fabrications</title>
  <link href="../portfolio_2/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

  <!-- filler code for top center text that redirects to landing page (on every page) -->
  <nav id="navlist" class="n-container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a class="n-smooth" href="" target="" rel="">Totally Fake Tiny Home Fabrications</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav-01a.png" alt=""></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav-02.png" alt=""></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav-03.png" alt=""></div>
      </li>
      <!-- fed midjourney the wrong prompt, correct later -->
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav-04-1.png" alt="1 bed"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav_05-2.png" alt="2 bed"></div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="nav-img"><img src="../portfolio_2/images/nav-06-3.png" alt="3 bed"></div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <footer>
    <!-- contact link/email goes here -->
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

At first I couldn't get the images to fit on the screen without vertical scrolling, which is when I wrote `.nav-img { max-height: calc(50vh - 50px); }` which at least mostly reduced vertical scroll (I mean it's like a scroll of maybe 2px). After that I tried altering max-height for the following block of code:

```css
.container ul li img {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    max-height: calc(50vh - 150px); /* adjust this value to your preference */
    max-width: 100%;
    display: block;
    object-fit: contain;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Which (1) fixed the height issue but made the images way too small, and also made the image only take up maybe 1/4 of the flexbox block allotted to it (per `<li><div class="nav-img"></div></li>` item) and (2) when I shrink the browser window they'll get so small they become invisible.

Comment: ChatGPT has put you on an overcomplicated path. `max-height:100%; width: auto; height: auto;` on the image and `display: flex;` on the parent should solve this.

Comment: UPDATE: Okay, adding `.container ul li { display: flex; }` and `.container ul li img { max-height: 100%; width: auto; height: auto; }` fixed it, but for some reason I can see the entirety of the image's container. Shouldn't that be resizing as well? Anyway thanks for the help, I really appreciate it.